# Javaw not terminated at launching external applications

Tags: java, runtime.exec

My application launches local Windows applications, such as the Calculator using JVM Runtime.

I am following the examples and the tutorial from http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

When I use a shell command-like dir-, my application terminates successfully. However, when I launch e.g. a calculator, my application only terminates, after I exit the calculator.
How can I decouple the launched application from my JVM??

Here is my code:

```
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println("Execing " + cmd[0] + " " + cmd[1] 
                           + " " + cmd[2]);
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
        // any error message?
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
            StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            

        // any output?
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
            StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

        // kick them off
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        // any error???
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You use `proc.waitFor()` which waits for the process to terminate. This is the cause why your application only terminates after the launched app terminates.

Why do you want to terminate your Java application immediatly anyway? Usually, there is nothing wrong with waiting for the process to terminate. Otherwise, you cannot get the exit value for the child process.

Comment: I would like my own threads to be terminated. The waitfor is not my problem, my main thread closes with exitcode 0. However, I would also like to close my JVM.